# Javascript pw generator - incorrect password lengths

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Caveat: I'm a JS newbie.

I'm playing with trying to make my own password generator using checkboxes to control the character groups which are included in the selections.

I started with a script I found online about 6 years ago (don't remember where) and after spending the past 3 days on w3schools I have tried combining some different examples to come up with a (mostly) working prototype.

Except, there's an odd behaviour in which if all checkboxes are selected, the length of password is as expected. But, if fewer than all checkboxes are selected then the password length is anywhere from 0 to maximum length of characters.

The expected result would be, regardless of number of checkboxes selected (one or more), the generated password length should be the same as the number selected from the drop-down list.

Could someone offer some suggestions on how to achieve the expected result?

Thank you.

**Original (almost):**

```js
function randomPassword(length) {
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()[]{}";
    var pass = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 76);
        pass += chars.charAt(i);
    }
    return pass;
}

function formSubmit() {
    passform.passbox.value = randomPassword(passform.length.value);
    return false;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  background-color: #cc66cc;
  border: 5px dashed #00f;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <body>
      <table>
       <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">
         <form name="passform">
          <p>
           <select name="length">
           <option value="1">01</option> <option value="2">02</option> <option value="3">03</option>
           <option value="4">04</option> <option value="5">05</option> <option value="6">06</option>
           <option value="7">07</option> <option value="8">08</option> <option value="9">09</option>
           <option value="10">10</option> <option value="11">11</option> <option value="12">12</option>
           <option value="13">13</option> <option value="14">14</option> <option value="15">15</option>
           <option value="16">16</option> <option value="17">17</option> <option value="18">18</option>
           <option value="19">19</option> <option value="20">20</option> <option value="21">21</option>
           <option value="22">22</option> <option value="23">23</option> <option value="24">24</option>
           <option value="25">25</option> <option value="26">26</option> <option value="27">27</option>
           <option value="28">28</option> <option value="29">29</option> <option value="30">30</option>
           </select>
          </p>
          <p>
           <input name="passbox" type="text" size="100" tabindex="1" style="padding-left: 5px;">
          </p>
    
          <p>
           <input type="button" value="Generate" onClick="javascript:formSubmit()" tabindex="2">
           <input type="reset" value="Clear" tabindex="3">
          </p>
         </form>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

**New Version:**

```js
function ranPass1(length) {
    var lower = "";
    var upper = "";
    var number = "";
    var spec1 = "";
    var spec2 = "";
    var spec3 = "";
    var chars1 = "";
    var pass1 = "";
    if (lowercheck.checked == true) {
        lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(lower);
    }
    if (uppercheck.checked == true) {
        upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(upper);
    }
    if (numbercheck.checked == true) {
        number = "0123456789";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(number);
    }
    if (spec1check.checked == true) {
        spec1 = "!@#$%^&*|?";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(spec1);
    }
    if (spec2check.checked == true) {
        spec2 = "`~.,;:-_";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(spec2);
    }
    if (spec3check.checked == true) {
        spec3 = "()[]{}\<\>";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(spec3);
    }

    for(var x1 = 0; x1 < length; x1++) {
        var i1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 71);
        pass1 += chars1.charAt(i1);
    }
    return pass1;
}

function formSubmit1()
{
    passform1.passbox1.value = ranPass1(passform1.length.value);
    return false;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  box-size: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal 17px/17px serif;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ccf;
  border: 1px solid #669;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
  height: 260px;
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #f90;
}

.select, .text, .button, .button2 {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 15px 5px 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #669;
}

.select {
  width: 80px;
  background: #aad;
}

.button {
  height: 25px;
  background: #aad;
}

#checkboxes {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.chkbx {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f00 !important;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
}

.bold {
  font: normal bold 23px/23px serif;
}

.text {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  background: #99f;
  height: 25px;
  width: 860px;
}

#passbox1 {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font: normal normal 17px/17px serif;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <body>
      <div class="box">
       <form name="passform1">
        <p>
         <select class="select" name="length">
          <option value="1">01</option> <option value="2">02</option> <option value="3">03</option>
          <option value="4">04</option> <option value="5">05</option> <option value="6">06</option>
          <option value="7">07</option> <option value="8">08</option> <option value="9">09</option>
          <option value="10">10</option> <option value="11">11</option> <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option> <option value="14">14</option> <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option> <option value="17">17</option> <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option> <option value="20">20</option> <option value="21">21</option>
          <option value="22">22</option> <option value="23">23</option> <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="25">25</option> <option value="26">26</option> <option value="27">27</option>
          <option value="28">28</option> <option value="29">29</option> <option value="30">30</option>
         </select>
        </p>
        <div id="checkboxes">
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="lowercheck" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> a - z <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="uppercheck" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> A - Z <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="numbercheck" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="spec1check" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> ! @ # $ % ^ & * | ? <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="spec2check" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> ` ~ . , ; : - _ <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="spec3check" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> ( ) [ ] { } &lt; &gt; <span class="bold">]</span></p>
        </div>
        <p>
         <input class="text" name="passbox1" type="text" tabindex="1" id="passbox1">
        </p>
        <p>
         <input class="button" type="button" value="Generate" onClick="javascript:formSubmit1()" tabindex="2">
         <input class="button" type="reset" value="Clear" tabindex="3">
        </p>
       </form>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: should'nt the line `Math.floor(Math.random() * 76);` be `Math.floor(Math.random() * x);`

Comment: I think it should be `i1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars1.length);` to prevent getting a random index out of the range of the `chars1` string.

Comment: Please add the following command immediately after the line `function ranPass1(length) {`: `console.log("Received length is: " + length);` and post what you see. My guess is that you will see `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Adding the console.log did not return "undefined". The result from [7 and one checkbox] selected is "Received length is: 7".

I can still use your suggestion as the console.log command will help me with future problems.

Comment: Thank you Titus. Your solution (i1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars1.length) corrects the apparent problem and seems to be the correct solution.

Comment: Muhammad, thank you for the try, but your solution does not work correctly. Firstly, "x" produces "Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined"; So, I assume you intended "x1". Secondly, "x1", while correcting the number of output characters, produces seemingly non-random results, with fewer than all characters, such as "aaaab", "aabbc", "aacba", "aaacb", etc, when I select only the lower case letters and 5 as a length.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you had wrong was as Titus pointed out was in correct form:

```
var i1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars1.length);
```

Now if you run the snippet it works as you intended.

```js
function ranPass1(length) {
    var lower = "";
    var upper = "";
    var number = "";
    var spec1 = "";
    var spec2 = "";
    var spec3 = "";
    var chars1 = "";
    var pass1 = "";
    if (lowercheck.checked == true) {
        lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(lower);
    }
    if (uppercheck.checked == true) {
        upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(upper);
    }
    if (numbercheck.checked == true) {
        number = "0123456789";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(number);
    }
    if (spec1check.checked == true) {
        spec1 = "!@#$%^&*|?";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(spec1);
    }
    if (spec2check.checked == true) {
        spec2 = "`~.,;:-_";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(spec2);
    }
    if (spec3check.checked == true) {
        spec3 = "()[]{}\<\>";
        chars1 = chars1.concat(spec3);
    }

    for(var x1 = 0; x1 < length; x1++) {
        var i1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars1.length);
        pass1 += chars1.charAt(i1);
    }
    return pass1;
}

function formSubmit1()
{
    passform1.passbox1.value = ranPass1(passform1.length.value);
    return false;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  box-size: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal 17px/17px serif;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ccf;
  border: 1px solid #669;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
  height: 260px;
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #f90;
}

.select, .text, .button, .button2 {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 15px 5px 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #669;
}

.select {
  width: 80px;
  background: #aad;
}

.button {
  height: 25px;
  background: #aad;
}

#checkboxes {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.chkbx {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f00 !important;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
}

.bold {
  font: normal bold 23px/23px serif;
}

.text {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  background: #99f;
  height: 25px;
  width: 860px;
}

#passbox1 {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font: normal normal 17px/17px serif;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <body>
      <div class="box">
       <form name="passform1">
        <p>
         <select class="select" name="length">
          <option value="1">01</option> <option value="2">02</option> <option value="3">03</option>
          <option value="4">04</option> <option value="5">05</option> <option value="6">06</option>
          <option value="7">07</option> <option value="8">08</option> <option value="9">09</option>
          <option value="10">10</option> <option value="11">11</option> <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option> <option value="14">14</option> <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option> <option value="17">17</option> <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option> <option value="20">20</option> <option value="21">21</option>
          <option value="22">22</option> <option value="23">23</option> <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="25">25</option> <option value="26">26</option> <option value="27">27</option>
          <option value="28">28</option> <option value="29">29</option> <option value="30">30</option>
         </select>
        </p>
        <div id="checkboxes">
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="lowercheck" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> a - z <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="uppercheck" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> A - Z <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="numbercheck" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="spec1check" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> ! @ # $ % ^ & * | ? <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="spec2check" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> ` ~ . , ; : - _ <span class="bold">]</span></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="spec3check" class="chkbx"> <span class="bold">[</span> ( ) [ ] { } &lt; &gt; <span class="bold">]</span></p>
        </div>
        <p>
         <input class="text" name="passbox1" type="text" tabindex="1" id="passbox1">
        </p>
        <p>
         <input class="button" type="button" value="Generate" onClick="javascript:formSubmit1()" tabindex="2">
         <input class="button" type="reset" value="Clear" tabindex="3">
        </p>
       </form>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you, neuro_sys for this solution; as per your credit to Titus, your suggestion is the same as Titus's.

I've tried numerous combinations to see if any errors display, but as of yet there is none. Therefore, although I cannot, yet, mark your solution with an upvote, I'll state your solution corrects the problem experienced. N.B.: While Titus's solution is worthy of recognition, as it is not a stand-alone response, thus it cannot be up-voted by others.

Comment: The solution makes sense, now. "var i1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars1.length);" because the previous iteration using the predefinition of "71" (or any other number) only worked with the predefined set of characters. Now, the set is variable, so the length must, also, be variable. Thanks, again Titus and neuro_sys.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `passform1.length.value` is a string (e.g. `"5"`). When comparing  integer to string javascript will silently coerce first value to string so

```js
console.log(2 < "1")
console.log(2 < "13")
```

effectively comparing two Strings length. What you need is to convert `passform1.length.value` to Number before passing to `ranPass1()` method one way to do it is with `parseInt()` method like this

```
ranPass1(parseInt(passform1.length.value))
```

Comment: Moti. Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the result is much the same as the original problem. When I select a length of 5 the console log states a length of 5 is received, but the output in the text field is only between 0 and 4 characters in length. I'll still take your suggestion and look at it some more for further understanding.